# Full page grid on Semantic-UI

Tags: semantic-ui

I'm using the Semantic-UI library and I'm having a little problem.

I created the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tsj8dsh/6/) with the HTML and CSS I currently have. However, the problem I'm trying to solve is not visible in the fiddle due to the height limitations of the result.

The image below demonstrates my problem. What I'm trying to achieve is to make the grid to take the whole space between the header and the footer. I have already used `height: 100%` but that creates a wide space between all my elements in the content.
[image: screenshot]

Any help will be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Just work on your CSS to make the changes you want to achieve. In your code I set the height of **.ui.container** to 100% and convert it to **.ui.segment**. Check the code below for your reference.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  padding: 0.25em;
}
footer {
  padding-bottom: 1.5em !important;
}
main.content {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Header */
header.ui.secondary.menu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
  margin-bottom: 0em;
}
header.ui.secondary.menu .item,
header.ui.secondary.menu .dropdown.item {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}
header.ui.secondary.menu .item:hover,
header.ui.secondary.menu .dropdown.item:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #21BA45;
}
header.ui.secondary.menu .active.item {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: #21BA45;
}
header.ui.secondary.menu .item {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 1.42857142em;
}
header.ui.secondary.menu .item:first-child {
  padding-left: 0;
}
header.ui.secondary.menu .item > i.icon,
header.ui.secondary.menu .item > i.dropdown.icon {
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}
header.ui.secondary.menu .disabled.item {
  padding-right: 1.42857142em;
}

/* Footer */ 
footer.ui.segment {
  padding: 0 1em 1em;
}
footer > .ui.divider {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
  color: rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
}

/* Full Grid */
.ui.full.grid {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
}
.ui.container{
  height:100%;
  border-radius:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Header -->
<header class="ui secondary menu">
  <div class="ui container">
    <a class="item" href="#">JSFiddle</a>
    <div class="right menu">
      <a class="item" href="#">
        <div class="ui green button">Sign up</div>
      </a>
      <a class="item" href="#">Log in</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Page Content -->
<main class="content">
  <div class="ui container segment">
    <div class="ui relaxed divided padded full grid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
          <h1 class="ui header">
            <div class="content">
              Contact
            </div>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui divider"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="eleven wide column">
          <form class="ui form" novalidate>
            <div class="field">
              <div class="two fields">
                <div class="field">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" />
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                  <label>Email address <span class="disabled-text">(Required)</span></label>
                  <input type="text" name="email" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label>Subject</label>
              <input type="text" name="subject" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
              <label>Message <span class="disabled-text">(Required)</span></label>
              <textarea rows="5" name="text"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="ui green button">Send request</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="five wide column">
          <h5 class="ui dividing header">
            <i class="bug icon"></i>
            <div class="content">
              Report a bug
            </div>
          </h5>
          <div class="ui list">
            <div class="item">
              <i class="info icon"></i>
              <div class="content">
                Provide as much information as possible.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <i class="info icon"></i>
              <div class="content">
                Explain exactly what has happened and what steps should we take to reproduce the problem.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h5 class="ui dividing header">
            <i class="comments outline icon"></i>
            <div class="content">
              Contacts
            </div>
          </h5>
          <div class="ui relaxed list">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="content">
                <div class="header">John Doe</div>
                <div class="description">
                  john.doe@jsfiddle.com
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="content">
                <div class="header">Jane Doe</div>
                <div class="description">
                  jane.doe@jsfiddle.com
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="footer ui vertical segment">
  <div class="ui divider"></div>
  <div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui right floated horizontal list">
      <a class="item" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="item" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui horizontal list">
      <div class="disabled item">Copyright &copy; 2016 JSFiddle.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```